# Adding ngIf condition to show and hide a div

Tags: angular

I have a div that i want to hide and show depending on value if exist in array.

At the moment i'm displaying all the data didn't know how to format my ngIf so i can the value that are in the filtred array.

I want to check if information.date is in the filtreArrayDate, if it is i want to display unless hide

```
<div *ngIf="user.recipient === selectedUser._id && showInformation(information)">
  //<div *ngIf="filtreArrayDate.includes(information.date)"> // throw error in includes
  <div class="information-date">{{ information.date | date:'EEEE'}} {{information.date | date:'d'}}  {{ information.date | date:'MMMM'}} {{ information.date |
    date:'yyyy'}}
  //</div>
 </div>
```

And this is my ts file it will get all the informations and will do a filter and get a filtred array. i want to use this filtred array to show/hide my div

```
initInformations() {
    if (this.informationSubscribe) {
      this.informationSubscribe.unsubscribe()
    }
    this.InformationSubscribe = this.informationProvider.getInformations(this.selectedUser._id).subscribe(
      ({ data }) => {
        this.informations = data['getInformationsByUser']
        const test = this.informations.map(a => a.date);
        const set = new Set()
        const filtreArrayDate = test.filter((a) => {
          const d = new Date(a).setHours(0, 0, 0)
          if (set.has(d)) {
            return false
          }
          set.add(d);
          return true;
        })
        if (this.informations.length === 10 && !this.enableInfiniteScroll) {
          this.enableInfiniteScroll = true
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.warn(`getInformations failed: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
      })
  }
```

Comment: u want to show div if filtreArrayDate get data? or what?

Comment: No I want to check if information.date is in the filtreArrayDate, if it is i want to display unless hide

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you are checking with filtreArrayDate.includes and it thorws error here.
try using **filtreArrayDate?.includes** and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you sir i added the ? at the moment it's displaying nothing instead of displaying the value in the array

Comment: so it solved the issue? if that's not probably i need a plunker to fix that issue. Can you create a plunker and share with the same or dummy data you are using?

Comment: No sir didn't solved it, i think it's not working like i want, maybe it's not the correct way to check if Date is in the array.

Comment: I looked your code again, filtreArrayDate  is a const and this is a local variable. You cannot refer the local variable in template. Declare this variable at class level, and then refer in code as this.filtreArrayDate = //your value and then refer the variable in same way you are doing in template. But still if that does not fix, need a plunker to see the issue.

Comment: In my console.log it's returning me the right Data an array of filtred Dates, i followed your response, it's only hiding the div so there's a problem in the ngIf, Sorry sir didn't know how to write my code in plunkr i did but it's a blank page. didn't figure out how to reproduce it :'(

Comment: Thank you sir for your patience, so when console.loging(filterArrayDate) it returns 
=> 
["Mon Jul 16 2018 15:32:50 GMT+0200 (CEST)", "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:33:46 GMT+0200 (CEST)", "Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)"]

And when doing typeof of the filtreArrayDate , it returns an Object

and when i do  console.log(typeof(this.information[1].date)) ==> String

Comment: Edit : when doing something like thisto check : console.log(filtreArrayDate.includes(this.informations[0].date))) 
It throw me an error : Property' 'includes' does not exist on type Date[]

Comment: @DeependerSharma Sir

Comment: ok, can you try indexOf (check something like filtreArrayDate.indexOf(your value) > -1

Check here for right syntax https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Lastly i can only help if plunker is there. so Please take your time and create the plunker for the same. Will surely help out that.